# I have Dynamic Property Names and Their Types stored in a Dictionary, how do i build a class dynamically out of it in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamic, assemblies

I have a dynamic Dictionary that gets filled at run time,

`Dictionary<string, Type>` (where string will have the property name and Type will have the type of the property ) now i want to generate a class out of it,

how do i achieve it in silverlight?

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        Dictionary<string, Type> props = new Dictionary<string,Type>();
        props["Id"] = typeof(int);
        props["Name"] = typeof(string);

        AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("AsemName"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("ModuleName");
        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = mb.DefineType("TypeName", TypeAttributes.Public);
        foreach(var name in props.Keys){
            typeBuilder.DefineField(name, props[name], FieldAttributes.Public);
        }
        Type type = typeBuilder.CreateType();

        object o = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);

        //Verfication:
        Console.WriteLine("Type is: " + o.GetType());

        foreach (var field in o.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" " + field.Name + " of type " + field.ReflectedType);
        }
```

Comment: This looks promising however on the assumption that the target goal is binding...  The only `AssemblyBuilderAccess` enum value available in Silverlight is `Run`.  For the type to be of use  in Silverlight it needs to be public currently its private.  The real doozy is that binding works against Properties not Fields, which in turn means generating both fields and Properties and the IL to go behind the properties.

Comment: public is easy - just add `TypeAttributes.Public` in the DefineType method. I used fields because it was less code - using properties is equally easy. I'll try to update the code soon.... Btw, I have never ever done anything in Silverlight, nor have I ever used System.Reflection.Emit - I just knew it must be possible :)

Comment: i got the answer from here http://mironabramson.com/blog/post/2008/06/Create-you-own-new-Type-and-use-it-on-run-time-%28C%29.aspx thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this at runtime (generate a class), what you could do is make use of the [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) available in .net 4.0.

Comment: This is probably true however I suspect that Kathy's next step is to attempt to do some data binding with these objects.  However Silverlight binding is based on reflection so is incompatible with an `ExpandoObject`